# Global variable in Javascript Namespace

Tags: javascript

I m new with Javascript Namespace, I have 2 buttons `Add` & `Remove`, I have the following script below.

```
<script>
    var nRow=1;
    function Add() {
        nRow++;
        alert(nRow);
    }
    function Remove() {
        nRow--;
        alert(nRow);
    }
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do to put this script in a namespace and call the functions `onClick` of the buttons. Please tell me how to put it in namespace and call the functions.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use namespacing.

Comment: @JustinSatyr, nested objects are considered "namespaces" in JavaScript. However, it's not the same as namespacing in other languages.

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I do not know, what it is, but in several sites it is reffered as "Namespace" only. for example: http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F320764%2FQuick-Tip-JavaScript-Namespaces&ei=7m-FUOS9D9CsrAeX0IHYCA&usg=AFQjCNEzoI2NK2iMBrNdGz5yLeJaOwYUDA

Answer (score 4):

Javascript doesn't have namespaces or classes. It has objects and prototypes. With that said, this should be what I believe you are asking for:

```
<script>
    window.myNameSpace = {
        nRow: 1,
        add: function () {
           this.nRow++;
           alert(this.nRow);
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.nRow++;
            alert(this.nRow);
        }
    };
    document.getElementById("MyAddButtonId").addEventListener("click", myNameSpace.add, false);
    document.getElementById("MyRemoveButtonId").addEventListener("click", myNameSpace.remove, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, JavaScript doesn't support namespaces. You could place it inside an object as follows:

```
var Increment = {
    nRow : 1,

    Add : function() {  
        this.nRow++;
        alert(this.nRow);
    },

    Remove : function() {  
        this.nRow--;
        alert(this.nRow);
    }    
}
```

You can then access the functions via `Increment.Add()` and `Increment.Remove()`.

Comment: Hi, when I have lots of objects in different files, how can I then put them all under the same namespace? I think I can't do `var Increment..` in every file, because that would create that variable multiple times I think?

Comment: You can define `Increment` as a `window` var, and then use `window.Increment.OBJECT_NAME.function`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So if I understand correct: using namespaces in JavaScript means put all of your code in an object?